# How to persist a List of Strings in Hibernate?

Tags: java, string, hibernate, list, annotations

I seem to have problems with mapping a List in Hibernate. In our project there a class `Card` with contains a class `Answer` with `Answer` containing a `List<String>`.

Is a `List<String>` mappable by Hibernate using annotations? I mean, since it does not have the `@Entity` annotation?

Regards

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use `@ElementCollection`:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="Nicknames", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
@Column(name="nickname")
public List<String> getNicknames() { ... }
```

**Source:** [7.2.3. Collections of basic types and embeddable objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues)

Comment: Just a question: Will `CollectionTable` automatically create a table called "Nicknames" if it is not created?

Comment: @BigDude if you let your schema be generated / updated by hibernate, then I'm guessing yes. But it's been almost 10 years since I used hibernate :-)

Comment: you're right, I tried it out and if I let Hibernate handle the creating/updating process, it will create and update the table defined within `CollectionTable` for me :) Thanks!

Comment: @ThiagoSuchorski I hardly ever use relational databases. But if I did, I'd probably use [jooq](https://www.jooq.org/).

Answer (score 3):

try

```
  @org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements(
        targetElement = java.lang.String.class
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name = "foo",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
    )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn(
        name = "POSITION", base = 1
    )
    @Column(name = "baz", nullable = false)
    private List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or see [this detail example](http://www.zabada.com/tutorials/hibernate-and-jpa-with-spring-example.php)

Comment: [`@deprecated use @ElementCollection`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionOfElements.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to store them in the same column as JSON (MySQL, [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-json.html) that also support indexing and binary JSON), you could simply use `io.hypersistence/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-52` library.

```
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)
})
public class YourEntity {
   @Column(nullable = false)
   @Type(type = "json")
   private List<String> fieldName = List.of();
   ...
}
```

See full guide [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-types-library)