# Getting issue to merge two objects in hibernate using Session.merge() function

Tags: java, hibernate, merge

I am trying to update single record in database using hibernate, so I want to merge updated object. I am having code to update object and return merged hibernate entity object like,

```
  protected <T> T updateObject(T o) {
        Session s = getSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T mergedObject = (T) s.merge(o);
        s.update(mergedObject);
        return mergedObject;
    }
```

When I am trying to update Multivalued attribute (e.g. List of addresses), If I add new address in list and call update fuction,

After **T mergedObject = (T) s.merge(o);** , mergedObject containing null value and transaction becomes failed. 
How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

If your object is list then you need to iterate over list and merge particular entity separately. Though you cannot use only String. The object must be a hibernate entity. With hibernate entity you can do like this.

```
    T mergedObject = null;
    if(o instanceof List){
        for(Object obj: o){
              mergedObject = (T) s.merge(obj);
        }
    }else{
        mergedObject = (T) s.merge(o);
    }
```

Comment: My object contains List as well as String. It is in the form like,public class User{
 private long id;
 private String userName;
 private List<String> schemas;
 private Name name;
 private Boolean active;
 private String password;
 private List<Ims> ims;
 private List<Address> addresses;
 private List<Email> emails;
}

Comment: May be you are looking for this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867130/hibernate-liststring

Comment: What will I do when object is of type User (java class)?

Comment: Have you done mapping of OneToMany for other list that you mentioned like Address, Email.

Comment: Yes. I've done mapping like,                                                                                                       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Email> emails;