# how to make Entity in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I need to create a Entityan entity called EventEvent which will have several fields like namename,description description,owner owner and others.I searched here and I added some dependencies but it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.app.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table (name = "events")
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String name;
private List<String> games;
private List<User> players;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private String description;
private User owner;

public User getOwner(){
    return owner;
}
public void setOwner(User owner){
    this.owner = owner;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
}

public double getLatitude(){
    return latitude;
}
public void setLatitude(double latitude){
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    return longitude;
}
public void setLongitude( double longitude){
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName( String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<String> getGames() {
    return games;
}

public void setGames(List<String> games) {
    this.games = games;
}

public List<User> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(List<User> players) {
    this.players = players;
}

}
```

[Here is an image of my folders and resources if helps to resolve the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY9hY.png)

here is my error message:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at com.example.app.AppApplication.main(AppApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: events, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(games)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:459) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
... 23 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually caused by `the org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List`.So, you need to put Mapping annotation (like: `OneToMany`,`ManyToMany` etc)

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity="your target enity", mappedBy="", fetch="Fetch Type")
private List<String> games;
```

Or for the basic entity (Integer, String)

```
@Column
@ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
private List<String> games;
```

Same you need to do for `private List<User> players;`

For more info visit the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at).

Comment: well it worked but i have some warnings or errors i'm not sure what are they. Here is an image of them https://ibb.co/dfkKGT .

Comment: @Todor which dialect you are using in the configuration? And please don't post the image. Also to maintain basic etiquette of  SO if your original problem as per the question then, please add another question with the new problem you are facing.

Comment: Well i would but stackoverflow don,t allows me to post so often questions XD

Comment: @Todor which dialect you are using in the configuration?

Comment: well it worked i didn't add `@Column
@ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
private List<String> games;` thank you for the help

Comment: @TodorDimitrov Great!!! Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate can not mapping a list of object.  In table form it must be foreign key to another table. Hibernate can use lazy loading mode to initializes Collection. See that post 
[Hibernate, List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867130/hibernate-liststring).