# Hibernate, saving a collection property in a single operation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I need a better understating of this behavior of hibernate, and wonder if I can get some light on the matter.
There are two objects, `Contact` and `Action` with one to many relation, i.e. one `Contact` can have many `Action`s associated with them.
What I am trying to understand is how can I store the collection of`Action`s (which is a property of `Contact`), when I store `Contact` to the database.
At the moment what I am doing is that storing `Contact`s first and then storing `Action`s.
The following is my code:
Model Objects:

```
public class Contact  implements Serializable{
    private Integer contactID;
    private String givenName;
    private String familyName;
    private Set<Action> actionSet = new HashSet<Action>();
}
public class Action  implements Serializable{
    private Integer actionID;
    private String actionNote;
    private Contact contact;
}
```

Hibernate Mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernate.model" schema="hibernatedb">
<class name="Contact" table="CONTACT">
    <id column="CONTACT_ID" length="500" name="contactID">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property column="GIVEN_NAME" generated="never" lazy="false" length="100" name="givenName" />
    <property column="FAMILY_NAME" generated="never" lazy="false" length="100" name="familyName" />
    <!-- one to many mapping with Action -->
    <set inverse="true" lazy="false" name="actionSet" sort="unsorted">
        <key column="CONTACT_ID" />
        <one-to-many class="com.hibernate.model.Action" />
    </set>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>

 <hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernate.model" schema="hibernatedb">
<class name="Action" table="ACTION">
    <id column="ACTION_ID" length="500" name="actionID">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property column="ACTION_NOTE" type="string" name="actionNote" />
    <!-- many to one mapping with Contact -->
    <many-to-one name="contact" column="CONTACT_ID"
        class="com.hibernate.model.Contact" lazy="false" cascade="save-update" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is how I am trying to store it at the moment:

```
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService{
    @Override
    public void addContacts(Contact contact) {

        contactDAO.addContact(contact);//saving the contact;
        if((contact.getActionSet()!=null)&&(contact.getActionSet().size()>0)){
            actionService.addAllActions(contact,contact.getActionSet());//saving actions, associated with the contact
        }

    }
}
```

See, there are two operations leading to saving the `Action`s, where as they are a property of `Contact`, and I believe that when the `Contact` is saved, the collection of `Action`s must be saved as well.
Please let me know the correct way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

`<set cascade="all"....`

This way, hibernate will save your Actions set when you are invoking save on your Contact entity.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356759/760757) answer for more details.

Also, see [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html).